# Как реализовать заглушку метода поиска в базе данных для тестового контекста?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, юнит-тесты

Изолирую зависимости от реальной БД при написании модульных тестов в проекте. Интерфейс репозитория имеет следующий вид:

```
public interface IRepository
{
   T Find<T>(int id) where T: class;
}
```

В реальном контексте метод реализован следующим образом:

```
public ConcreteDBContext : DBContext, IRepository
{
//some code
   public T Find<T>(int id) where T : class
   {
      return this.Set<T>.Find(id);
   }
}
```

Вопрос: как правильно реализовать такой метод в FakeDBContext? И от чего наследовать сам контекст, кроме самого интерфейса IRepository?

Comment: достаточно только от _IRepository_ если вам надо просто проверить, что данный метод вызывается

Comment: @Grundy нет, нужно проверить обращение и поиск в объекте, являющемся макетом реального EF контекста

Comment: тогда зачем FakeDBContext? используйте ConcreteDBContext :)

Comment: @Grundy, тогда это будет обращением к реальной базе данных, что недопустимо при модульном тестировании

Comment: а тогда что именно вы хотите протестировать? если вы вместо бд будете использовать что-то еще - что покажет ваш тест? что где-то еще работает?

Comment: при создании экземпляра FakeContext в конструкторе будет создаваться коллекция из реальных сущностей EF, в которых будут тестовые данные. Эти данные будут впоследствии выводиться, скажем, на страничку MVC-приложения, или через WCF передаваться на консоль. Т.е. FakeContext позволит иммитировать реальный запрос к базе данных, при этом сам тест будет выполняться за миллисекунды, в отличие теста с реальным контекстом, на выполнение которого может уйти гораздо более длительное время. Т.к. тестов будет ОЧЕНЬ много, это имеет значение. Плюс исключается возможность конфликтов при обращении к базе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33146/discussion-between-grundy-and-klutch1991).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если в местах, где вы используете db context, зависимость имеет тип `IRepository`, то вам достаточно наследовать заглушку от этого интерфейса (для этого зависимости и интерфейсы и нужны :)). Как правило, для каждого теста вам нужна будет своя реализация метода `Find<T>`. Поэтому правильнее говорить о моках.

Самый правильный способ работать с моками -- использовать мок-фреймворки. Их великое множество: Moq, RhinoMock, NSubstitute и проч. Синтаксис их будет немного отличаться, однако суть работы с моками всегда одна:

1. Создаем мок-объект.
2. Устанавливаем, что должен возвращать нужный нам метод мок-объекта
   при вызове с такими-то параметрами.
3. Проверяем, что нужный нам метод был вызван (опционально).

Например, с использованием NSubstite это будет выглядеть так:

```
var personId = 1;

var repo = Substitute.For<IRepository>();
// для id = 1 возвращаем объект
repo.Find<Person>(personId).Returns(new Person { Name = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
// для всех остальных id возвращаем null
repo.Find<Person>(Arg.Is(a => a != 1)).Returns(null);

var someObjectThatUsesRepo = new SomeObjectThatUsesRepo(repo);
someObjectThatUsesRepo.SomeMethod();

// проверяем, что метод вызвался ровно один раз
repo.Received(1).Find<Person>(personId);
```

Comment: А что если создать собственный mock?

Comment: @klutch1991 не понял вопроса.